# Does the biblical understanding of "coming together" require physical presence?

Tags: greek, ecclesiology, local-church

Due to the COVID-19 pandemic, the church I attend is meeting online. However, some members have expressed reservations about this, fearing if the Scriptural teaching for churches to "assemble" meant to assemble **physically**. When the Bible teaches about "coming together" or "assembling," it uses terms such as συνάγω (*sunago*, 4863, e.g. Acts 20:7), συνέρχομαι (*sunerchomai*, 4905), and ἐπισυναγωγή (*episunagoge*, 1997). Do these Greek words require physical presence between those assembling, or are the terms broader than this? It doesn't appear to me that they require physical presence (e.g., *sunago* in Matt. 12:30; John 11:52; 1 Cor. 5:4), but I'd like a more professional understanding of these terms.

Thanks,

The Editor

Comment: There were no other ways of being together other than physical presence in late antiquity, since there were no phones or radios or televisions then.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Lucian. The fact you pointed out is interesting. However, what if the word itself was broader than the physical? The Greek word _sunago_ (translated "came together" in Acts 20:7 NKJV) doesn't always appear to require physical presence. It's used to refer to siding with Jesus (Matt. 12:30), the gathering of all people in the universal church through Jesus' death (John 11:51‐52), and the "gathering together" of Herod and Pilate against Jesus (Acts 4:26-27), which was non-physical (Luke 23:7, 11). Do these passages confirm a broader understanding of _sunago_? Thanks!

Comment: The problem with your question (specifically, the latter part of the second sentence, and beginning of the third) is that it does not address a specific text. This is technically against the rules of the site, as detailed on meta. Just because *coming together* can sometimes mean *to conspire*, doesn't mean that within the specific context of a specific verse it can still reasonably carry the same connotation.

Comment: @Lucian We could make the text Acts 20:7, for example, which uses the word _sunago_ and is considered precedent for meeting on Sundays. While I agree they "sunagoed" physically in this case, is such denoted by the word, or is it implied in this case due to the lack of technology? Thanks!

Comment: Either they **met** together (to break bread), or they **planned / agreed / conspired** to do so, or they **joined forces** to do so. These are the basic meanings of the word. The term is never employed to refer to synchronizing various individual actions (such as private prayer) to take place simultaneously (by persons which are not physically present together).

Comment: @Lucian I wonder if "joined forces" would be the idea (though we certainly couldn't exclude "met")? If so, then we can do the same over the Internet if necessary. Is this an option?

Comment: No. The idea is that nowadays we can see and hear each other in real time, without actual physical presence. So you are asking whether ancient Greeks, were they alive today, would employ the word in question, in its *first or basic* meaning (that of *meeting*), for certain twentieth-century technologies.

Comment: @Lucian That is something I'd like to know! What can we do to get the answer to this question? Do you have the answer?

Comment: No one can *objectively* answer this question, which is also why it does not *properly* belong on this particular Q&A site, that's the whole point.

Comment: @Lucian Maybe we can. What does _sunago_ mean in 1 Corinthians 5:4? (Note that Paul wasn't physically present with the Corinthians when writing this.)

Comment: In light of the surrounding two verses, it would seem to refer to Paul being present-minded, though absent-bodied, at the judgment of one of their (fallen) brethren (presumably after being previously briefed on the dispute in question either in writing or by envoy). Then their (physical) judicial gathering as a church (following Matthew 18:15-20), along with Paul's own (informed) opinion on the matter, both together condemn, through Christ's power invested in them, the aforementioned brother.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the "meaning" of sunago. [1Co 7:5 NASB95] [5] Stop depriving one another, except by agreement for a time, so that you may devote yourselves to prayer, and come together again so that Satan will not tempt you because of your lack of self-control.  *Orrr... if there is a health crisis that makes it ill-advised.* The problem with funny-mentalists is that they read correspondence addressed to people long gone and consider it LAWS for readers far removed from that context. IE: Be smart, not wooden.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great question especially in view of Heb 10:25 which says:

> [Do] not giving up meeting together, as some are in the habit of
>   doing, but encouraging one another--and all the more as you see the
>   Day approaching.

This question can be rephrased as, Must meeting together be a physical meeting or can it be otherwise?

The noun translated "meeting together" here is ἐπισυναγωγή (episunagógé) and only occurs here and in 2 Thess 2:1 which talks about the gathering of the saints to Jesus at His coming.  It is from the cognate root συνάγω (sunagó) = to bring or gather together, and occurs frequently in the NT.

Before offering some comments, let me first say that I am a strong believer in meeting together as a local congregation/group (in various ways) on a regular basis to encourage one another, share our faith and learn more about Scripture and Jesus.  However, in the current circumstances, is there a NT precedent for meeting in some other way, rather than physically?  I believe there is.  Here are some examples:

- 1 Cor 5:3, 4, For my part, even though I am not physically present, I am with you in spirit. … So when you are assembled and I am with you in spirit, …
- Phil 1:27, …  I'll hear that you are firmly united in spirit, united in fighting for the faith that the Good News brings …
- Phil 2:2, then make my joy complete by being like-minded, having the same love, being one in spirit and of one mind.
- Col 2:5, For though I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in spirit and delight to see how disciplined you are and how firm your faith in Christ is.
- 1 Cor 6:17, But whoever is united with the Lord is one with him in spirit.
- John 4:24, For God is Spirit, so those who worship him must worship in spirit and in truth …

Without going into a detailed exegesis of these passages, I note that one of the various meanings of the Greek word πνεῦμα (pneuma), "spirit" given BDAG is (#3c) "spiritual state, state of mind, disposition".  Thus, it might be possible to understand Paul's wish to be absent in body but present by his spirit as a kind of meeting minds.  This is a vague approximation of what we moderns now call a virtual meeting online.

Many of Paul's letters (and others) were written precisely because these apostles could not be physically present and so they tried to do this by the written word.

In short, the modern practice of quarantine is a Biblical practice as set out in Leviticus to limit the spread of communicable diseases; and we do well to implement it as we can.

Comment: Thank you! 1 Corinthians 5 uses sunago (which not only is the cognate root of episunagoge but also the term used in Acts 20:7). In addition, it's used to refer to siding with Jesus (Matt. 12:30), the gathering of all people in the universal church through Jesus' death (John 11:51‐52), and the "gathering together" of Herod and Pilate against Jesus (Acts 4:26-27), which was non-physical (Luke 23:7, 11). These passages with sunago further show it doesn't require physical gatherings.


Does the Greek of 1 Corinthians 5:4 imply that Paul's spirit itself was "sunagoing" with the Corinthians?

Comment: Not quite.  However, in 1 Cor 5:4 we find, "when you are assembled" = συναχθέντων (synachthentōn), I am with you in spirit.  The preposition used is σὺν (syn) which is closely related to the this verb.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Dottard. Young's Literal Translation (YLT) translates 1 Corinthians 5:4 as saying "ye being gathered together, also my spirit," as if his spirit is "also" doing the action of "being gathered together." However, does the Greek more accurately mean that the Corinthians alone were gathered together, making Paul's spirit _with_ their assembly but not _part of_ it?

Comment: I am not sure one could press the Greek that far.  I prefer the BLB here which says:  "in the name of our Lord Jesus, of you having been gathered together and of me in spirit, with the power of the Lord Jesus,"  This suggests that all are gather together in spirit (a kind of one mind).  Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say you're not sure the Greek can be pressed that far, was that in reference to my first point from YLT, or was it about the second claim, where's Paul spirit is _with_ the assembly but not _part of_ it? Thanks!

Comment: @TheEditor - it was aimed at the second comment.  All that Greek says is that Paul is with them (gathered with them) in spirit.  This is a kind of meeting minds, or in the spirit is if Paul were physically present or something like that.  All that the Greek says is that Paul is with them in spirit (but obviously absent physically).

Comment: So the usage of _sunago_ in 1 Corinthians 5:4 includes the Corinthians AND Paul's spirit. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: That is what it says.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This suggests that _sunago_ can be used for remote gatherings, since Paul's spirit could even "_sunago_" with them while they were "_sunagoed_". (Obvious Anglicization of the Greek on my part, haha, but what I'm saying should be understood.) Thank you!

Comment: The word in question never *properly* refers to doing things simultaneously (whilst physically apart), nor to thinking about someone (in prayer). If the word's basic meaning would have normally included such options, then Paul's observations would have been somewhat superfluous. The fact that he did care to mention them in the first place proves, if anything, quite the opposite of what you are trying to convey.

Comment: That is not entirely the point of the question nor answer.  The fact is, that Paul was "with" them in spirit, as per 1 Cor 5:4.  A situation such as the present "social isolation" was never envisioned in NT times and so a words specifically describing it cannot be expected to exist.  Despite this, Paul still wants to meet with them in spirit.

Comment: @Lucian I also asked you about 1 Corinthians 5:4 in the above comments section.

Comment: @Dottard: You seem to interpret *[when] you [are] gathered together, and my spirit* as *[when] you [are] gathered together with my spirit* and/or *[when] you and my spirit [are] gathered together*. But the text seems to simply read *you, gathered together in the Name of our Lord Jesus Christ, and my spirit, with the power of our Lord Jesus Christ, deliver such an one unto Satan, for the destruction of the flesh, that the spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord Jesus.* There seems to be an inversion there, at the beginning, and the conjunction refers to *to deliver*, rather than *to gather*.

Comment: @Lucian - I read the text very simply: "in the name of our Lord Jesus having been gathered together you and my spirit with the power of our Lord … "  (My translation of 1 Cor 5:4) - that appears to be a meeting via spirit.

Comment: @Dottard: As I've already explained, you seem to think that both *yours*and *my spirit's* are to be lumped with the (previous) aorist of *gathered*, whereas I say that both the (previous) aorist of *gathered* (itself a genitive, and the *yours* that goes along with it), as well as *my spirit's*, are to be lumped with the (following) aorist of *deliver*. *Your gathering's and my spirit's delivery of X to Y*, as opposed to *your and my spirit's gathering's delivery of X to Y*.

Comment: @Lucian - Even if that is true, it does not alter the outcome.  Paul is telling the people to either gather or deliver, and to do so with his spirit present, in the power of our Lord Jesus.

Comment: @Dottard: It kind of does, though, since his spirit is condemning along with their congregation, rather than spiritually congregating with them.

Comment: Okay, so there are two differing schools of thought in this thread. If I'm understanding correctly, Dottard sees the Corinthians and Paul **both** "_sunagoing_," while @Lucian sees the Corinthians "_sunagoing_" **alone** but **condeming** with Paul. Is this correct?

Comment: @TheEditor: It would seem so. Notice how each aorist is determined by a similar expression; the former, *congregating*, by *in the name of the Lord Jesus Christ*, and the latter, *condemning*, by *with the power of our Lord Jesus Christ*.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this, @Dottard?

Comment: I think @Lucian is ignoring 1 Cor 5:3, "For my part, even though I am not physically present, I am with you in spirit. … ".  But Lucian is welcome to his view.  V4 also says, "So when you are assembled and I am with you in spirit, and the power of our Lord Jesus is present,"  Which ever way one interprets/translates these two verses, Paul is present by his spirit.

Comment: @Dottard: Lucian is not ignoring anything (as can be clearly glimpsed from his last comment on the main post), rather merely pointing out that the proposed interpretation of the following verse, though not technically impossible, seems, nevertheless, slightly forced. Paul's mental presence at the judgement (his knowledge of that person's deeds enabling him to form an opinion, and thus pass legitimate condemnation) does not seem to be expressed by the verb in question; rather, the latter seems only to apply to the physical gathering, from which the Apostle himself was notoriously absent-bodied.

Comment: @Lucian - that is the point - Paul was present by his spirit as you correctly point out.  Now, whether you say it was for a judgement in the sense of the verdict or the trial (krima vs krisis) is almost beside the point.  The fact remains that Paul was present by his spirit.

Comment: @Dottard: Having been already warned by moderators, on a different thread, not to engage in any more prolonged discussions, I hereby end this conversation on the following note: Paul's presence is not expressed by the verb *to congregate*, mentioned in the OP.