# Colossians 2:5 I am present with you in spirit. Is this literal or metaphor?

Tags: romans, colossians

> Romans 8:9
> You, however, are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if in fact the Spirit of God dwells in you. Anyone who does not have the Spirit of Christ does not belong to him.

Romans 8:9 is true literally concerning the Spirit of Christ.

What about the spirit of Paul in Colossians 2:5?

> For though I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in spirit and delight to see how disciplined you are and how firm your faith in Christ is.

Comment: A [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/46788) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apostle Paul could have used many prepositions, but he used σὺν, and in doing so, it is hard to fathom he meant anything but a literal presence with those in Colosse. Of course, when I say “literal,” I do mean literal, but not literally present in the body. Rather, he was literally present **in the spirit**.

The means by which this presence is achieved, though he be not with them in his body, is by means of the spiritual unity of the body of Christ. By being in Christ, Christians are united spiritually to one another by means of the Holy Spirit.<sup>1</sup>

For this reason, on the road to Damascus, the Lord Jesus asked Paul, “Why did you persecute me?”<sup>2</sup> Did the apostle Paul ever persecute the Lord Jesus himself? Certainly not. But, the apostle Paul did persecute Christians, those who are “in Christ,” and by doing so, he persecuted Jesus, too, for Christians and Jesus Christ himself are united spiritually. For this reason, the Lord Jesus said, “...inasmuch as you did it to one of the least of these my brethren, you did it to me.”<sup>3</sup> Indeed, the apostle Paul said that Christians in the body of Christ are “body parts of one another.”<sup>4</sup> Therefore, “if one body part suffer, all the body parts suffer with it...”<sup>5</sup>

Because of this organic unity, the apostle Paul was literally present in the spirit with those in Colosse, just as those in Colosse were present with Paul, and every Christian present with one another throughout the entire world, by means of the Holy Spirit who unites all Christians.

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> 1 Cor. 6:17</sup>
        <sup><sup>2</sup> Acts 9:5</sup>
        <sup><sup>3</sup> Matt. 25:40</sup>
        <sup><sup>4</sup> Rom. 12:5</sup>
        <sup><sup>5</sup> 1 Cor. 12:26</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**What about the spirit of Paul in Colossians 2:5?**

For though I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in spirit and delight to see how disciplined you are and how firm your faith in Christ is.

**SPIRIT.**

The Greek word translated as “spirit” is “pneuma”,(from the Greek verb “pneo” =breath or blow) the basic meaning is of which is “wind” the movement of air. Wind is a force that we can feel but cannot be touched or seen
In the scriptures, the writers used it in a variety of ways and translators have recognized the multiple uses of "spirit." It is used to mean wind,  breath, spirit, one's own spirit, spirit persons, and Holy Spirit.

Paul expression,in Colosians 2:5  "I am present with you in spirit,"  means the following.

**A person’s individual spirit, the emotions,thoughts , feelings and actions that emanate from a person’s figurative heart.**

A few other examples of the same meaning in the scriptures.

Mark 14:38 (NASB)

> 38 "Keep watching and praying that you may not come into temptation;
> the spirit is willing, but the flesh is weak.”

John 13:21  (NASB)

> 21 "When Jesus had said this, He became troubled in spirit, and
> testified and said,

“Luke 1:80 (NASB)

> "And the child continued to grow and to become strong in spirit,
> Truly, truly, I say to you, that one of you will betray Me.”

Answer (score 2):

Just as in English, the Greek πνεῦμα (pneuma) has a variety of meanings - eight according to the BDAG classification.

The third of these meanings is "**a part of human personality**", eg, 1 Cor 4:21, Gal 6:1, Eph 4:23, 1 Peter 3:4, 2 Cor 7:1, Col 2:5, 1 Cor 5:3-5, 7:34, Mark 8:12, etc.

This meaning might also be translated as "disposition" or "attitude" as is, "By not sharing, the child displayed a selfish spirit".  A few versions actually capture this idea:

- NLT: For though I am far away from you, my **heart** is with you. And I rejoice that you are living as you should and that your faith in Christ is strong.
- CEV: Even though I am not with you, I **keep thinking** about you. I am glad to know that you are living as you should and your faith in Christ is strong.

As Lucian has reminded me, this answer has similar ideas.

[Does the biblical understanding of "coming together" require physical presence?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/46788/does-the-biblical-understanding-of-coming-together-require-physical-presence)

Comment: You nailed it also. I really wish that you weren't a Trinitarian because I could TRULY be with you in SPIRIT if you were not and that's an understatement.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - Thanks for your kindness.  A good friend of mine once said that we have the most to learn from those with whom we disagree.  Thank you good friend.

Answer (score 2):

It is a metaphor, just like the one that is still commonly in use in many Christian circles. “I can’t make it to the meeting, but I will be with you in spirit.” Nobody present would be attempting to interact in any way with that person’s spirit during the meeting.

From the context, Paul is concerned here that people will be deceived by persuasive words. He reminds them that he is present in spirit as a way to motivate them to continue to walk in Christ. Does this mean that he is observing them in a supernatural way in the spirit? I don’t think so, or he would have done that more frequently and not relied on the reports of others, such as in 1Cor 5:1.

> It is actually reported that there is sexual immorality among you, and
> of a kind that even pagans do not tolerate: A man is sleeping with his
> father’s wife. NIV

The case in Corinthians can help us understand this concept more clearly. Imposing one’s will upon others through spiritual means is more the domain of the occult. Our focus must always be on the truth which comes from God, his Word, and his Spirit, not human spirits. If God wanted Paul to have additional influence on the excommunication meeting he could have teleported him there just as easily as allowing him to send his spirit. There are at least two instances of teleportation in the New Testament. But if Paul’s statement is taken literally, it is more of an out of body experience or something equivalent to astral projection.

Paul, or someone he knew, did apparently have a very vivid experience of traveling to heaven and receiving special revelation.

> 2 Cor. 12:2 I know a man in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught
> up to the third heaven. Whether it was in the body or out of it I do
> not know, but God knows.

Even so, this would not involve interacting with other humans. In the parable of the rich man, God did not permit the rich man to go back as a spirit to speak to his brothers. Assuming that Paul were able to travel in spirit, what would he have done once he arrived, besides frighten everyone? It is not hard to imagine how spirit projection could lead to a lot of confusion, to say the least. If Paul could influence his churches by being there in spirit, he would have done it much more often and there would have been a lot fewer problems that he would have needed to address in his letters.

Why bother to write specific letters at all, and focus rather on books for the benefit of all Christians? Why risk undertaking dangerous travels if he could go everywhere in his spirit? If that were a possibility, it would have been practiced and explained much more widely in scripture. It would have become much more widespread in the early church and beyond. In the preceding verse Paul says,

> 3 Although I am absent from you in body, **I am present** with you in
> spirit, and I have already pronounced judgment on the one who did
> this, just as if I were present. BSB

The active participle, **παρὼν** , is used here which can convey the idea of repeated or continuous action. Paul is not saying that his spirit will travel to be with them during the meeting, but but that it is always with them. How? Because of our unity in the Spirit of God.

> 1 Cor 6:17, But whoever is united with the Lord is one with him in
> spirit. NIV

It is this unity in the Spirit which would lead the church to the same conclusion Paul arrived at, which is that incest must be dealt with decisively. Paul is strongly encouraging the church to listen to the Spirit and do the right thing by reminding them that he is with them in the Spirit, i.e., act as if I were there. In Colossians 2:5 he uses the present as if he is always with them in spirit.

> τῷ πνεύματι σὺν ὑμῖν εἰμι

Paul emphasized later that ultimately God is the source of wisdom and revelation.

> Let us therefore, as many as are perfect, have this attitude; and if
> in anything you have a different attitude, God will reveal that also
> to you; Phil 3:15 NASB

If Paul could have organized an online meeting would he have? Yes, because he could have made his case more forcefully. As he said earlier,

> But I will come to you soon, if the Lord wills, and I shall find out,
> not the words of those who are arrogant but their power. 1 Cor 4 18-19

He knew his physical presence, or the congregation being able to communicate with him in a more direct way, would have the most impact. He didn’t want to rely on just being there with them in spirit. It was a metaphor, but more importantly, Jesus is there where two or more are gathered.

> So when you are assembled and I am with you in spirit, and the power
> of our Lord Jesus is present.., 1 Cor 5:4 NIV

Paul makes the same case in the verse following the passage in question.

> Colossians 2:6 So then, just as you received Christ Jesus as Lord, continue to live
> your lives in him, 7rooted and built up in him, strengthened in the
> faith as you were taught, and overflowing with thankfulness. NIV

Answer (score 1):

If I am a fan of FC Barcelona and suffer after having watched its latest catastrophic loss to Bayern 2:8 on TV, I can write to FC Barcelona fans in Barcelona: "Although I am not with you, but in spirit I am with you, for I also share your suffering and pain".

But if I am not interested in football at all (such strange people exist!), even if I am a citizen of Barcelona I will say: "Even though I am here with you, my fellow Barcelonians, but I am not with you in spirit, because I deem it stupid to be nervous about such a vanity as a loss of a football game, and even if all Barcelona goes stupid like this, I would not share this spirit, but I am in spirit united with those Christians all over the world who suffer for Turkish government ill-advisedly turning ancient Byzantine churches into mosques".

Comment: I may be a non-Trinitarian, which you are not, consequently I can't always agree with what you say, but you nailed this one. Love your football analogies. I too deplore  Erdogan's wrong headed decisions on Byzantine churches, which of course sadly include that jewel of history, the Hagia Sophia.

Comment: @OldeEnglish Thanks for your comment and estimation! Even though I used to be a professional tennis player, still enjoy watching football even more than tennis:) As to Trinidadian view, I am not Trinidadian out of, so to say, good life, but out of [theo]logical necessity derived from the Holy Scripture, that urges me to embrace the paradox of the Trinity.

Comment: Yes, the "Trinidadian" was automatic "correction" of my spell-check which eluded my attention, yet, it means the same in Spanish. As to translations, I do not much care about them for I read original Greek, and those theologians, heroes of faith in times of persecutions, like e.g. St Athanasius, who, without any outward compulsion, found it a [theo]logical necessity to admit the Godhead of Jesus Christ, also read not translations but original Greek. Even a great Jewish scholar Daniel Boyarin admitted the Trinitarian interpretation of Exodus more plausible philologically than a Rabbinic one.

Comment: So, you read and understand "Koine" Greek?? Further Q: If the  Greek is to be the standard for "correctness" then why did the writers, or should I say COPIERS see fit to remove the name of God (JHVH, commonly expressed as JeHoVaH), shown more than 7000 times in the  Hebrew, and replace the all important with "Kurios" and "Theos" and then use the same for Jesus, as these are mere titles and do not clearly differentiate between the two, if they weren't also biased towards the Trinity. To be frank: We don't know what the ORIGINAL Greek actually said. Lord's Prayer: Let your NAME be SANCTIFIED !!

Comment: Even most pious orthodox Jews, more than two centuries before the incarnation of God's eternal Logos, translated the Hebrew Bible to Greek and used PIPI for tetragrammaton and also κύριος and θεός for God; they were not Trinitarians. Yes, "Let Your name be sanctified": the name is "Father" this being His eternal name, He eternally is Father, thus even before the creation, and since He is eternally Father, that analytically means that He eternally has Son-the Offspring, who is Logos, His co-eternal and co-Creator of the universe. It is clear and how can one not see it perfectly eludes my grasp.

Comment: p.s. and, yes, I do read koine and not only koine but also ancient and Byzantine Greek

Comment: Wow! That's impressive on the Greek understanding. Yes, I knew about the "Septuagint" but here again the "original" translation is lost to all. We only have that which was copied after the incarnation, when the copyist's could have been influenced. Coming back to the name, I have to "respectfully" point out that "Father" is also just a title, as is the "Son". Come "Armaggedon" God will no longer allow his name to be profaned. See Ez, 39:7, See also Ex, 3:15-18 in the NWT, which quite rightly restores the widely accepted derivative "name" of "Jehovah", which is not a "title", back to the OT.

Comment: Again: only Jesus "revealed the name" of God to people (John 17:26) and this name is "Father" as in the Lord's Prayer. This name is eternal, so that there was not a situation when God was not Father, and as He was always Father, ergo, He always had Him to whom He was Father, even before the world was made (John 17:5). Now, there can be either God or creation, tertium non datur, as Romans used to say, and since both Father and the Logos are co-Creators (John 1:1-3) it excludes any possibility of attaching the Logos to the order of creation, and thus Logos is also  God, no less than the Father

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112195/discussion-between-olde-english-and-levan-gigineishvili).

Comment: @TonyChan Dear Tony, thanks for estimating my a bit of playful response so highly, for I guess it was you who are the distributor of the bounty points.

Comment: Actually, your benefactor was Lucian. He must be a fellow football fan. :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is very curious. First the answer is clearly evident, even though not joined as bodies, joined in *spirit*, for the same purpose there is. However, why would *spirit* (in this case soul) be more important than body? It's not true that soul surpasses body as they equally that the same weight in matters of Salvation, for it's the **soul** (psychic aspects) that **dictates** the behaviour of the **body**. So if the body is in a good state then it's because of the soul being well, the contrary is also valid (this is, the contrapositive). Then, what is the function and difference between body and soul:

First there is a comparisson between the *body* and a *house* in **1 Corinthians 3:16-17**:

> Do you not know that you are God's **temple** and that God's Spirit dwells
> in you? If anyone destroys God's temple, God will destroy him. For
> God's temple is holy, and you are that temple. (ESV)

And the is the whole body as the indivual members **1 Corinthians 12:27** (the same happens with the soul) :

> Now you are the body of Christ and individually members of it. (ESV)

As we all know, a house can't move as the body can't move. And the earth is also compared to the body, so what moves is truly the soul that makes the body moves, for the soul is the movement, and we see it in **Psalm 93**:

> The Lord reigns; he is robed in majesty;
> the Lord is robed; he has put on strength as his belt. Yes, the world is established; *it shall never be moved*. (ESV)

and the comparisson again with a **house** (**Psalm 93:5**)

> Your decrees are very trustworthy;
> holiness befits your house,
> O Lord, forevermore.

We see that **water** is compared to the **soul** in **Psalm 23:2-4 (ESV)**:

> He makes me lie down in green pastures. He leads me beside still
> **waters**. He restores my **soul**. He leads me in paths of righteousness for
> his name's sake. Even though I walk through the valley of the shadow
> of death, I will fear no evil, for you are with me; your rod and your
> staff, they comfort me.

So, we conclude that what united both earth and water, body and soul is truly the Spirit of G'd (in the Unity) permitting this perfect connection. When Paul uses "For though" we see that even if he's not in body, he joins the *movement* we described, which move? Actually he speaks of the soul in general (the sum of all individual souls) not a particular one, for if he talks about his own soul it's not necessary to go out of it to share with others, then he can or not be in his own body, but if he doesn't have a body, he can't share the same *spirit* with other souls, only if he's saved (for there is one soul attached to exactly one body), and soul becomes the Holy Spirit (in the Unity).

Answer (score 1):

Romans 8 is about a Christian's daily life in accordance with the Holy Spirit. Paul contrasts this godly life against a carnal Christian's life fulfilling the desires of the flesh. The phrases "in the flesh" and "in the Spirit" in Romans 8:9 should be interpreted accordingly. These represent carnal and godly lifestyles respectively.

The context of Colossians 2:5 is different. Here was a church that Paul hadn't visited yet (2:1). Yet, he was attempting to persuade them to stay protected from "speculative arguments" that threatened the integrity of the gospel (2:4). He had to connect with them before he could impress upon them the greatness of Jesus Christ (1:21–2:23) and about the dangers of certain heresies. That's why he mentions his toil for those in that region of Asia (2:1).

```
I say this
         so that no one may deceive you
                              through speculative arguments
For though I am **absent in body**,
           I am **with you in spirit**,
                rejoicing to see your order ... (2:4-5a)
```

Paul, therefore, wanted the Colossians to know that his love for them transcended the physical distance between them. In other words, Paul's absence in Colossae shouldn't stand in the way of them accepting his important message. Surely, he wasn't *literally* present with them - either in body or spirit. This expression is not about Paul traveling out of his body, in the spirit, to be a part of the Colossian fellowship. It's certainly a *metaphorical* usage to indicate how connected he was with them through the unity of the Body of Christ.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).